# Display of doctors by category, ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Apologies in advance for my english...

We have a list of categories and a list of doctors, you need to output as follows:

- category1

  - item1
  - item2
  - item3
- category2

  - item1
  - item2
  - item3

Here is what I was able to write:

```
function renderChatList() {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let categoriesArr = [];

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        categoriesArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        categoriesArr.forEach((category) => {
          getDoctorsGroup(category.id, category.title);
        });
      }
    };
    xhttp.open(
      "POST",
      "http://localhost/domen/api/readCategories.php",
      true
    );
    xhttp.send();
  }
  renderChatList();

  function getDoctorsGroup(id, title) {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let doctorsArr = [];

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        doctorsArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let html = "";
        
        html += '<div class="members-group">';
        html += '<h4 class="members-group_title">';
        html += `<span class="text">${title}</span>`;
        html += '<span class="icon"><i class="far fa-ellipsis-h-alt"></i></span>';
        html += '</h4>';
        html += '<div class="members-group_list">';
        doctorsArr.forEach(doctor => {
          if(doctor.category == id) {
            html += '<div class="member">';
            html += '<div class="member-image user-image">';
            html += `<img src="images/dist/doctors/${doctor.avatar}" alt="${doctor.name}">`;
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="member-info">';
            html += `<h3 class="member-name truncate-text-item">${doctor.name}</h3>`;
            html += `<p class="member-job truncate-text-item">${doctor.job}</p>`;
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
          }
        })
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';

        // Insert group into list
        const container = document.querySelector(".chat-list_members");
        container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);

      }
    }
    xhttp.open(
      "POST",
      "http://localhost/domen/api/readDoctors.php",
      true
    );
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

**is it possible to optimize the code, or improve?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few improvements which I will recommend:

1. Use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of XMLHttpRequest. Fetch is supported by almost every major browser and definitely serves as good replacement for XMLHttpRequest.
2. Utilize template literals properly. I can see template literals getting used properly at some places, but converting multiple strings into one template literal string will avoid cluttering. Also, instead of creating HTML as string, proper DOM elements can also be created using `createElement` but I am not sure which one is performant. Maybe someone else will give us some input here.
3. Utilize functional nature of JS to avoid cluttering. A lot of code can be broken even further into smaller logical pieces.
4. Use `id` in `querySelector` at line `document.querySelector(".chat-list_members")`. The reason being, you can have multiple HTML elements with same classname. This leads to a possibility of bug or wrong element getting selected. Id is a better choice in these cases.
5. Do error handling properly. The code seem to be handling cases when api is successful. A good code should also deal with cases when api fails or some error occurs.

Here is how, I will restructure the code:

```javascript
function renderChatList() {
    fetch('http://localhost/domen/api/readCategories.php', { method: 'POST', })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          data.forEach((category) => {
            getDoctorsGroup(category.id, category.title);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Error handling here like alert/toast/popup etc
      });
}

renderChatList();

function getMemberHtml(doctorsArr, id){
    let html = ""
    doctorsArr.forEach(doctor => {
      if(doctor.category == id) {
        html += `<div class="member">
          <div class="member-image user-image">
            <img src="images/dist/doctors/${doctor.avatar}" alt="${doctor.name}" />
          </div>
          <div class="member-info">
            <h3 class="member-name truncate-text-item">${doctor.name}</h3>
            <p class="member-job truncate-text-item">${doctor.job}</p>
          </div>
        </div>`;
      }
    })
    return html; 
}

function getDoctorsGroup(id, title) {
    fetch('http://localhost/domen/api/readDoctors.php', { method: 'POST', })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let html = "";
        html += `<div class="members-group">
          <h4 class="members-group_title">
            <span class="text">${title}</span>
            <span class="icon"><i class="far fa-ellipsis-h-alt"></i></span>
          </h4>
          <div class="members-group_list">
            ${getMemberHtml(data, id)}
          </div>
        </div>`;
        
      // Insert group into list
      const container = document.querySelector("#chat-list_members");
      container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Error handling here like alert/toast/popup etc
    });
}
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

Comment: Thank you, I will take your advice under consideration. I am self-taught, so it is important for me that you share your opinion!

Answer (score 3):

**General Suggestions**

- There's no need to put the data type like "arr" into the variable name, it's just clutter. The fact that a variable name is plural should be a good indication that we're dealing with an array (or array-like value). (e.g. change categoriesArr to just categories)
- Prefer [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) over .forEach(). .forEach() came after for-in in helped fix many of the issues that for-in creates. In es6, for-of was introduced which can do everything that .forEach() can do and more, like iterating over any iterator,  continue/break, async iteration, etc.
- Prefer the fetch API over XMLHttpRequest - it's meant to replace XMLHttpRequest, and it's more powerful and user-friendly than it's predecesor.
- It looks like each call to getDoctorsGroup() is making the same network request to retrieve a resource. It would be better to either fetch this resource beforehand and pass it in to getDoctorsGroup(), or cache the result. There's no need to fetch the same resource many times. Also note that your code currently has a bug where content will get added to the DOM depending on the order in which these network requests get resolved, so if they're resolved out of order, your categories may render out of order.
- On a related note, if you have control over the backend API, these requests should probably be GET requests, not POST requests, since you're just trying to retrieve a resource, not modify it.

**XSS Concerns**

XSS is one of the most common ways websites get hacked into, likely because it's so easy to slip up and create a vulnerability. While it's possible for an expert to safely use .innerHTML by following [a number of escaping rules](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) to cleans unsafe data before inserting it into a template string (users of languages like PHP do this kind of expert work all the time), it's easier to just stay away from it in Javascript, particularly because alternative, safer tools exist to manipulate the DOM (like `document.createElement()`).

You may find that the built-in DOM API isn't very convenient to use. There's nothing wrong with creating a little helper function to make working with the DOM a little nicer. Here's one that I like to use:

```
// USAGE:
// The following javascript...
//   const myNewElement = el('div', { class: 'my-class' }, [
//     el('p', {}, ['Hello World!']),
//     el('hr'),
//   ])
//
// ...would produce the following DOM structure:
//   <div class="my-class">
//     <p>Hello World!</p>
//     <hr>
//   </div>
function el(tagName, attrs = {}, children = []) {
  const newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(attrs)) {
    newElement.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
  newElement.append(...children);
  return newElement;
}
```

Even with these precautions, some additional escaping may still be necessary. For example, when settings the src attribute of an image to `"images/dist/doctors/${doctor.avatar}"`, it might be a good idea to escape `doctor.avatar` with encodeURIComponent.

Here's an example of how I might put your code together. I'm using the el() helper function as defined above to showcase one way you might go about replacing .innerHTML with something else.

```
// Initialize //

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  document.querySelector('.chat-list_members')
    .append(await createChatList());
});


// Components //

async function createChatList() {
  const [categories, doctors] = await Promise.all([
    requestCategories(),
    requestDoctors(),
  ]);

  return fragment(
    categories.map(({ id, title }) => createCategory({ doctors, id, title })
  ));
}

function createCategory({ doctors, title, id }) {
  return el('div', { class: 'members-group' }, [
    createCategoryHeading({ title }),
    el('div', { class: 'members-group_list' }, [
      ...doctors
        .filter(doctor => doctor.category === id)
        .map(createDoctor)
    ])
  ]);
}

function createCategoryHeading({ title }) {
  return el('h4', { class: 'members-group_title' }, [
    el('span', { class: 'text' }, [title]),
    el('span', { class: 'icon' }, [
      el('i', { class: 'far fa-ellipsis-h-alt' })
    ]),
  ]);
}

function createDoctor({ name, job, avatar }) {
  return el('div', { class: 'member' }, [
    el('div', { class: 'member-image user-image' }, [
      el('img', { src: `images/dist/doctors/${encodeURIComponent(avatar)}`, alt: name }),
    ]),
    el('div', { class: 'member-info' }, [
      el('h3', { class: 'member-name truncate-text-item' }, [name]),
      el('p', { class: 'member-job truncate-text-item' }, [job]),
    ]),
  ]);
}


// Services //

const requestCategories = () => (
  fetch('http://localhost/domen/api/readCategories.php', { method: 'POST' })
    .then(response => response.json())
);

const requestDoctors = () => (
  fetch('http://localhost/domen/api/readDoctors.php', { method: 'POST' })
    .then(response => response.json())
);


// Utilities //

// Warning: Some attributes such as href, src, style, etc can not receive untrusted data without additional cleaning
// (i.e. because of potential attack values such as href="javascript:maliciousCode()")
function el(tagName, attrs = {}, children = []) {
  const newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(attrs)) {
    newElement.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
  newElement.append(...children);
  return newElement;
}

function fragment(children = []) {
  const newFragment = new DocumentFragment();
  newFragment.append(...children);
  return newFragment;
}
```